# ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (10061)

Tags: mysql

Всех приветствую.
Проблема с MySQL. Давно им не пользовался, решил зайти, создать новый Хост, но не получилось. Решил переустановить, но он затребовал РУТ пароль, который я не помню. Переискал весь инет, способы по восстановлению пароля, но ни один не подходит. То у меня my.ini нет. На mysqladmin –uroot –pqwerty shutdown выдает следующее...
"mysqladmin: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (10061)'
Check that mysqld is running on localhost and that the port is 3306.
You can check this by doing 'telnet localhost 3306'".
На команды mysql выдает ошибку в теме письма.
Уже не знаю что делать. Помощь плиз.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел я выход из данной ситуации. Может тоже кому поможет...
Короче...надо удалить абсолютно все файлы с компа. Не забываем, что существуют скрытые файлы. Делаем отображение скрытых файлов и удаляем всё, где в названии есть "mysql". Я сначала по папкам поискал (Program Files, Prigram Data, Users), а потом тупо через поиск ввел в проводнике и всё что нашел на Диске С, удалил. Далее установка прошла успешно. Старый пароль не спрашивал, а попросил ввести новый.